# Plotting Bar Graph by Years in Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot this DataFrame which records various amounts of money over a yearly series:

```
from matplotlib.dates import date2num

jp = pd.DataFrame([1000,2000,2500,3000,3250,3750,4500], index=['2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016','2017'])
jp.index = pd.to_datetime(jp.index, format='%Y')
jp.columns = ['Money']
```

I would simply like to make a bar graph out of this using PyPlot (i.e pyplot.bar).

I tried:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))

xvals = date2num(jp.index.date)
yvals = jp['Money']
plt.bar(xvals, yvals, color='black')

ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis_date()

plt.show()
```

But the chart turns out like this:

[image: weird bar chart]

1. Only by increasing the width substantially will I start seeing the bars. I have a feeling that this graph is attributing the data to the first date of the year (2011-01-01 for example), hence the massive space between each 'bar' and the thinness of the bars.
2. How can I plot this properly, knowing that this is a yearly series? Ideally the y-axis would contain only the years. Something tells me that I do not need to use `date2num()`, since this seems like a very common, ordinary plotting exercise.
3. My guess as to where I'm stuck is not handling the year correctly. As of now I have them as DateTimeIndex, but maybe there are other steps I need to take.

This has puzzled me for 2 days. All solutions I found online seems to use `DataFrame.plot`, but I would rather learn how to use PyPlot properly. I also intend to add two more sets of bars, and it seems like the most common way to do that is through `plt.bar()`.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: There are *many* tutorials and examples to show you how to plot bar graphs.  Here, I think your sticking point is that you insist on making dates out of your labels.  DOn't bother.  They are already in the order you want -- just plot with those four-digit strings as your series of X values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either do

```
jp.plot.bar()
```

which gives:

[image]

or plot against the actual years:

```
plt.bar(jp.index.year, jp.Money)
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks so much for this. It is as simple as I would've thought. Would you mind explaining a bit more how ```plt.bar(jp.index.year, jp.Money)``` this works? Why is it jp.index.year? I got stuck because ``pyplot.bar()`` requires sequence of scalars and I was not sure how to get there from DateTimeIndex.

Comment: `jp.index.year` extracts the years from the dates (index) as a series of scalar as needed by `pyplot.bar)(`.