# How do I make the year appear on the histogram?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a histogram with the no. of transactions against the years but the output of the graph was incorrect.

```
labels = list(set(d2['flat_type']))
labels = ['1 room','2 room','3 room']
levels_values = d2[['flat_type','transactions']]

values = levels_values['transactions']
values_1room = values[levels_values ['flat_type'] == '1 room']
values_2room = values[levels_values['flat_type'] == '2 room']
values_3room = values[levels_values['flat_type'] == '3 room']

plt.figure(1) 
plt.hist(values_1room,  
         alpha=0.5, 
         color=['blue'])
plt.plot([2006,2007,2008,2009,2010])
plt.title("1 room",fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('Number of transactions',fontsize=15)
```

Instead of showing a histogram, a straight line appeared and the years that I have indicated did not appear on the graph as well. Can someone advise how should I revise my coding so that the year will appear on the y-axis and the no. of transactions will appear on the x-axis.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not called a histogram, it's called a [bar plot](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotting Bar Graph by Years in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61351572/plotting-bar-graph-by-years-in-matplotlib)

Comment: [Using year-week column as x-axis for bar chart in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70835242/)